# INSERT OPENQUERY inserts two rows

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, linked-server

I have MySQL server linked in MS SQL server and I tried to find the best way for inserting data into MySQL table.

I tried to use OPENQUERY SQL table-valued function and I write next code to call MSSQL stored procedure that call MySQL procedure:

```
SELECT
        *
FROM OPENQUERY(LINKEDSERVERNAME, 'Call db.procTest(''11111'');')
```

and my proc definition is:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `procTest`(
    IN testStr varchar(20))
BEGIN

    declare ProcessedParam enum('false', 'true');

    insert into db1.table1(ReceivingDateTime, Number, CNumber, TextD, Recipient, Processed, NewService)
    values(now(), '1122', '0000', '11111', '0001', 'false', 1);

    select 1;
END
```

To be worse, I pass the parameter value into procedure call, and MySQL proc accepts that parameter, but doesn't do anything with it.

After executing this code, in db1.table1 I've found two same rows, with same *ReceivingDateTime* value.

If I execute *procTest* directly from MySQL Workbench Query Editor, it inserts only one row. *Table1* haven't any triggers.